# Accessing Node Proxy Server from a locally hosted file

Tags: node.js, proxy, server, localhost

I'm trying to access a node proxy server running on my local machine from somewhere else(specified later). I've tried setting proxy listening domain to 0.0.0.0 with with port 8888. The file that will send request to the proxy server is hosted using a simpleHttpServer at 127.0.0.1 with port 4444 on another computer. In this file, I'm sending the request to http://my_local_ip:8888 (I'm assuming this is where the Node Proxy lives on my computer). However, I'm get connection timeout for some reason. Does anyone see problems with this approach?

Comment: try to bind your node js server in 'my_local_ip' with port 8888 and close any firewall that might blocking connections.

Comment: @alex-rokabilis How would I be able to do that?

Comment: now you tell node to bind on 0.0.0.0:8888 try to change this ip with your local ip(the ip your router gives on your pc) something like 192.168.1.54:8888